# Why does this python queue code process items multiple times?

Tags: python, queue, multithreading

The following is a testcase I created. Why does every process print the number 1 to 5 and are the numbers not divided over the processes?

code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from subprocess import *

from Queue import Queue
from Queue import Empty

import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process

def main():
    r = Runner()
    r.run()

class Runner(object):
    processes = []

    def run(self):
        q = Queue()
        for t in range(1,6):
            q.put(t)

        for pi in range(1,4):
            p = Process(target=self.runFromQueue, args=(q,))
            p.start()
            self.processes.append(p)

        for p in self.processes:
            p.join()

        print "Finished!"

    def runFromQueue(self, q):
        try:
            while True:
                number = q.get_nowait()
                print str(number)
                q.task_done()

        except Empty:
            pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Ouput:

```
$ ./test_threads.py 
1
2
3
4
5
1
1
2
3
2
4
3
5
4
5
Finished!
```

Expected ouput:

```
$ ./test_threads.py 
1
2
3
4
5
Finished!
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Queue package is not process aware, it only works for threads. The following happens in your example:

1. Create Queue and fill with numbers
2. Fork 4 processes. This copies the memory content into each subprocess, including the filled Queue
3. Each process empties its copy of the queue

You have to use the [Queue](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) class provided by multiprocessing.